# Passport Reddit not working in production

Tags: node.js, heroku, passport.js, reddit

I'm developing an app with Login with Reddit Oauth using Passport.js and the passport-reddit strategy. It works fine during local development however when I push the code to Heroku I get `internal server error` when I authorise my app with my Reddit account.

When I enter the command `heroku logs --tail` in the terminal it gives the following message:

> 2020-10-22T06:33:44.482074+00:00 app[web.1]: TokenError
> 2020-10-22T06:33:44.482092+00:00 app[web.1]: at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:358:12)
> 2020-10-22T06:33:44.482093+00:00 app[web.1]: at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:405:16)

can someone please help with this issue?